Reviews don't show up when ui is loaded
I have a flutter app and now I create the profile page , but when I load the page the Reviews average doesn't appear, only when I swipe to ReviewsTab category is syncing , here is the code and a gif https://imgur.com/a/9EfTqRH so you understand better the issue. What I should add in the init state?The code is too big I don't know how to show it
        double _averageRating = 0;
      int _numberOfReviews = 0;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initializationFuture = _initializeTabController();
        initUser();
        print("Current userId in NewUserProfile: $userId");
      }

   class ReviewsTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;
  final Function(double, int) onAverageRatingCalculated;

  ReviewsTab({required this.userId, required this.onAverageRatingCalculated});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(userId)
          .collection('Reviews')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        final reviews = snapshot.data?.docs ?? [];

        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          if (reviews.isEmpty) {
            onAverageRatingCalculated(0, 0);
          } else {
            double totalRating = 0;
            for (var doc in reviews) {
              totalRating += (doc['rating'] as num?)?.toDouble() ?? 0;
            }
            double averageRating = totalRating / reviews.length;
            onAverageRatingCalculated(averageRating, reviews.length);
          }
        });

        if (reviews.isEmpty) {
          return Center(child: Text('No reviews yet'));
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8), // Reduced top padding
          itemCount: reviews.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ReviewItem(
              review: reviews[index],
              isFirst: index == 0,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ReviewItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final QueryDocumentSnapshot review;
  final bool isFirst;

  const ReviewItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.review,
    this.isFirst = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 8,
        right: 8,
        top: isFirst ? 0 : 4, // No top margin for the first item
        bottom: 4,
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 2,
            offset: Offset(0, 1),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                review['reviewerName']?.toString() ?? 'Anonymous',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              _buildRatingStars(review['rating'] as int? ?? 0),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Text(
            review['comment']?.toString() ?? '',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          Text(
            _formatDate(review['timestamp'] as Timestamp?),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.grey[600],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRatingStars(int rating) {
    return Row(
      children: List.generate(5, (index) {
        return Icon(
          index < rating ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
          color: Colors.amber,
          size: 18,
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  String _formatDate(Timestamp? timestamp) {
    if (timestamp == null) return '';
    DateTime date = timestamp.toDate();
    return '${date.day}/${date.month}/${date.year}';
  }
}


I'm not sure what your onAverageRatingCalculated does, but make sure that it calls setState so that Flutter knows it needs to rerender the widget with the new average value that you calculated.

You should fetch the review details data in the initState method of the widget having defaultTabController and do the calculation to calculate the average there only as your widget to show average is not in review tab widget. Then pass that data to the Reviews tab widget.
